# Codefluent tablediff.sql bloat

Tags: codefluent

I am using CodeFluent for some time now and I am really, really happy with it. However, the tablediff that is generated seems to contain unnecessary changes every time. Does anyone know if these changes can be turned off?

1. All [nvarchar] (max) columns are set to [nvarchar] (max) every time, even if they are already [nvarchar] (max).
2. All defaults seem to be set every time, even if they are already there. In our diff there are almost 100 _trackLastWriteTime and _trackCreationTime.
3. Constraints are dropped and added

Why is this a problem?

1. Since the tablediff is so large it is hard to see and verify the
   'real' changes
2. Executing the tablediff takes much longer, especially
   on a large database
3. The dropping of constraints reverses changes we
   made to primary keys and indexes, sometimes even resulting in
   creating only a heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the generated diffs script is to get the right database schema after building the model during the **development phase**. It can contain useless statements as long as the final database schema is ok.

To upgrade the database in a production environment you should use the [SQL Server Pivot Script producer](https://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/10/10/the-new-sql-server-pivot-script-producer/). The Pivot Script producer generates an XML file (or a zip file) that contains the list of tables, stored procedures, functions, etc. of the database. The Pivot Runner read this file, and create or upgrade a database to the state describe in the XML file. As it generates and executes SQL statements directly (without generating a script file), the PivotRunner does less operations than the diffs script.

*If needed, you can have full control on what the pivot runner does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36426389/2996339*

This schema shows the development and deployment workflow:

[image]